# sort results from database by cell value

Tags: php, mysql

i have database like this

```
============================
| id | name | value | key  |
============================
| 1  | sara |       |   1  |
============================
| 2  | sara |       |   1  |
============================
| 3  | sara |   1   |      |
============================
| 4  | jhon |       |   1  |
============================
| 4  | jhon |   1   |      |
============================
```

i want first to get only one result for each name
my expected output

```
jhon
sara
```

i use

```
select * from my_table
```

but it's display all names

and need to sort table by key cell
my expected output with sort

```
sara (3 keys)
jhon (1 key)
```

Comment: I don't get it: Why do the two rows containing `jhon` have the same id? And why does `sara` have  3 keys (I count only 2)? You will have to explain your problem much better before you can expect somebody to help you.

Comment: what is the status of this question? if it's solved, then the answer given should be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are searching is called `group by`.

```
SELECT name, SUM(key) FROM my_table GROUP BY name
```

You can also use other aggregate function (not only SUM), maybe you want

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY name
SELECT name, COUNT(key) FROM my_table GROUP BY name
```

Search for some examples for `group by` (also here on Stack Overflow) and check out the different results.

The other function you are searching for is called `order by`.

Please read some book or tutorials about sql, this is pretty basic stuff.